# NSError and activating it while polling JSON data - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nserror

Trying to understand how/why `NSError` works in this case.  I'm trying to do a simple `UIAlertview` when the `JSON` query returns no data (either the server is sending it or the user is not on internet).  I have looked at about a dozen different answers and am just confusing myself more and more.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        kLatestChartDataURL];

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];


    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData  {


    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *theArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSDictionary *dict0 = [theArray objectAtIndex:147];

    if (NO) {

        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                     message:@"Data failed to load."
                                                     delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Retry",nil];
        [message show];
    }
```

I've also tried:

```
if (!theArray) { 

and

BOOL results = [NSArray etc...
```

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated, I've also looked at the developer docs and Cocoa is Mygirlfriend examples, and my brain has turned to mush at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *theArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

if (!theArray) { // DO THIS CHECK
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                 message:@"Data failed to load."
                                                 delegate:self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Retry",nil];
    [message show];
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"parsed data");
    NSDictionary *dict0 = [theArray objectAtIndex:147];
}
```

If any error occurs while getting `json` from `NSData` then it will be recorded in object of `NSError`. So if this object is nil means there is no error while parsing json, and if that object holds value means there is some issue while parsing.

Comment: changed (NO) to (error!=nil) and still not working .. here's the error message 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: make sure your responseData should not be nil.

Comment: Your `if` statement is incorrect. You need to check `if (!theArray)`. Only check `error` if the method returns `nil`.

Comment: okay, got it to the !theArray version, turn off my wifi to simulate and still getting the "data parameter is nil" crash.    I have my dictionary and the value assignments in the else section.  Wifi on things still work okay.

Comment: @Koerner You mean when you turn off wifi then only you are getting crash ?

Comment: Yes, yesterday when I was tinkering on the code it was crashing with same error when the server was busy.  So I've been using turning off wifi to simulate it not getting the data (maybe not the best option, but what came to mind).  I've put the full code on github  https://github.com/koernerd/jsonchart using the !theArray version

Comment: @Koerner I have comment above your NSData should not be nil. I can see that your NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:                       kLatestChartDataURL]; line holds nil value. You are not receiving response from your web service.

Check by printing this line NSLog(@"Length = %d",[data length]);

Comment: ok, I think I got what you're saying, sorry, brain not braining tonight.  I'll test this out vs server fail versus my wifi off.  Thanks for the patience.

Comment: @Koerner URW :). Just have the practise of having condition check for Network Reachability before calling any web service.